# Eclipse Luna StackOverflow exception at Build Time

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, java-8, eclipse-jdt, eclipse-luna

I get this SO exception when building the workspace.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-06-27 16:01:29.327
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Rebuilding".
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.mentionsAny(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:915)
       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.mentionsAny(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:915)
```

My workspace has a lot of projects, with a lot of compile errors, which I'm trying to resolve.

Any clues why this might happen?

*Windows 8.1 

JDK 8 build 05*

Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers 
Luna Release (4.4.0)
Build id: 20140612-0600

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like Eclipse bug [432541](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432541) or the duplicate [434800](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=434800).

Unfortunately these bugs are still open.

Update: This bug is now marked as fixed in Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 (and subsequent releases).